# Ruby Cucumber: Chrome Driver failed to start

Tags: ruby, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to Launch chrome browser from Ruby Cucumber framework. But i see it is throwing me an error.

I followed the solutions from stack overflow i.e., to re install chrome application but i see it apparently not working for me.

Here is the code from `env.rb` file.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
Before do
  Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path="E:/chromedriver.exe"
      $driver=Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome)

end
```

Error is see is as follows.

```
E:\Eclipse\LoginMercury>cucumber
*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (https://github.com/adoxa/ansic
on/) to get coloured output on Windows
Feature: Registration and Login to Mercury Portal

  Scenario: Registrating new user in Portal      # features/Login.feature:3
  unknown error: chrome failed to start
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.3,platform=Windows NT 6.1 x86) (Selenium::WebDr
iver::Error::UnknownError)
  ./features/support/env.rb:4:in `Before'
    Given Load Home page                         # features/step_definitions/Log
inStep.rb:1
    When User need provide Username and password # features/step_definitions/Log
inStep.rb:6
    Then Login to Portal                         # features/step_definitions/Log
inStep.rb:10

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/Login.feature:3 # Scenario: Registrating new user in Portal

1 scenario (1 failed)
3 steps (3 skipped)
0m1.180s
```

As I am using Windows 7, I've tried with older versions of chrome driver even.(V2.3). Yet i failed.
Can someone help me in moving further.

Thanks...!!!!

Comment: What version of chrome are you running?  If you have chrome v64-66, you'll want chromedriver 2.37.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error when using an older version of the chrome driver such as your version 23 and the latest version of chrome browser.

Upgrade and replace the driver, that your automation path is using for it, to the latest version 27 and this will fix this error.

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Cheers.